# Class App\MySSOServer does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a starter in laravel. i was creating a sinup form. i just copied a program from the link given by my trainer. Any one please help me. I am stuck with my task.

Error:Class App\MySSOServer does not exist

coding is given below

```
 <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\MySSOServer;
    class MyServerController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(MySSOServer $ssoServer){
           $command = isset($_REQUEST['command']) ? $_REQUEST['command'] : null;
           if (!$command || !method_exists($ssoServer, $command)) {
               header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
               header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
               echo json_encode(['error' => 'Unknown command']);
               exit();
           }
           $user = $ssoServer->$command();
           if($user)
              return response()->json($user);
          }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is your `MySSOServer` class under the `App` namespace?

Comment: I am done with laravel. Now working with codeigniter